# What is ROM Copy Section in Startup

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

As I am quite a new to using compilers, So far what i understood is thet an object file contains:

1. .data section
2. .text section (sometimes also reffred as code section)
3. .Debug section

While playing aroung with section placement i came accross a terminology named as "ROM copy table"
Can somebody please explain what is a ROM copy table/section?
What is the purpose of this?

Thanks for your helps

Comment: Where did you come across it?

Comment: I had came accross it in Tasking compiler

Comment: Been ages since I used Tasking, but I think it's simply the default initialization values that should get copied from ROM flash to RAM .data during startup.

Answer (score 3):

When you are programming a small computer with no operating system (for example, a microcontroller) you may physically program your program onto a ROM chip (read-only memory) and have a RAM chip to hold your variables. When your program starts it has to initialize all the variables to their starting values. The easiest way to do this is to have them all at adjacent addresses (i.e. a section), store the starting values in the ROM next to the program, and use `memcpy` at the beginning of the program to copy the starting values to the actual variables in RAM. You can't make a RAM chip with pre-programmed starting values.

On modern microcontrollers, both ROM and RAM are in the microcontroller chip, not separate chips, but the design is still the same.

Depending on the terminology of your specific linker, the place where the initial values are stored in ROM, the place where they end up in RAM, or both, could be called the "ROM copy section", although I don't believe it's standard terminology.

Comment: you dont use memcpy to copy .data nor memset for .bss, chicken and egg problem.   the code is just a copy loop in the bootstrtap

Comment: @old_timer Such a bootstrap loader can be written in any language capable of doing the task. We once had an environment that enabled us to use plain C for the job, including `memcpy()` and `memset()`. But this is not common. ;-)

Comment: you have the chicken and egg problem using C to bootstrap C.  It is also quite inefficient.  and probably other reasons why you dont see it done that way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague so not possible for a complete/accurate example.

There are three main sections historically named .text, .data, .bss, although any particular toolchain is free to call them whatever they want, do not even have to use the word section.

.text is the code (and depending on instruction set some read-only data and/or based on the toolchain and programmer all of the read/only data) (code plus pool).

.data is the initialized globals or local globals as I like to say

```
int x=5;
...
int fun ( void )
{
   static int y=3;
```

and any other item that is read/write and initialized before the compiled code entry point is called.

.bss is zeroed globals

```
int z;
int more_fun ( void )
...
```

an MCU normally means there is a non-volatile memory (rom/flash/eeprom/...) and some ram and the processor and peripherals.

When we run a program on our computer the operating system loads our program into ram, and can choose to have the loader extract these items to the right locations, or the binary can be constructed so that the operating system loader simply copies the image to ram and runs it.

On an MCU or other similar bare-metal system the code itself has to initialize the ram.  If the programmer wishes to use these types of global information, then before they expect that information to be available it needs to be placed.  The non-volatile memory is...non-volatile...so that is where one would need to store .data and information about .bss.  There is no need to store all of the .bss zeros on flash, you only NEED to store the start address and the number of bytes.

The programmer through linking and bootstrap (a tightly married couple) (bootstrap in this case the assembly based code that happens before the compiled code runs, that prepares the system to run compiled code) places the .data and .bss information in flash somewhere.  Some code in the bootstrap takes the flash offset, the ram offset and number of bytes for .data and copies those bytes.  Likewise the bootstrap takes the address in ram and number of bytes for .bss and zeros that data.

Debug is not a requirement for a binary, it is optional. usually it is not put on flash, it is in the binary for some file formats (.elf for example) but the bytes on flash are usually the loadable portions.  A debugger would read the matching elf file and/or download/flash and run/reset to know it matches then use the strings and other info in the file to make stepping through the code, etc more user friendly.

It is possible certainly that a binary may have a rom monitor or other such things that fall under the category of debug. Bug debug is not typical/required.

Depending on toolchain you may have a .rodata for read only that is not part of .text (gnu does this on newer versions).  And again the names .text, .data, .bss are more of a habit and not a hard requirement. Not using those names would create confusion with experienced users and might have a negative view of your product so I suspect most just use those names.

This ROM Copy table, sounds like the binary is generated in such a way that there is information that needs to be copied from rom to ram before continuing execution.